# Why is alert(); not working in Firefox 121.0.1 (on Windows)?

Tags: javascript, firefox

I was very surprised today when I noticed (while working on some JS code) that `alert({any text})` wasn't working any more. It just didn't show the msgs, but console also showed no errors.

I've tested in other browers and confirmed that my typing is ok and it still is working - so the question is why it stoppped working.

I've disabled all extensions and it still isn't working. Is is ripe enough to officially report it or could I check anything else?

Comment: Can't reproduce - `alert("hello")` works on Firefox 121 on Windows for me.

Comment: perhaps you've stopped the site from showing alerts - it's an option when you've had a few

Comment: Or whatever code you wrote isn't being executed, but cached code is. Who knows. I find it *very* hard to believe that functionality like `alert()` would randomly stop working. Browsers are mature products. We're not talking about IE in the early 2000s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: rebooting the machine has "fixed" the problem. And to be clear: even opening dev console (on a new page) and typing "alert('hi');" wouldn't work!

Before this q accumulates more downnvotes, I thought I'd "answer" and close it - though it's not satisfying. But I guess finding a satisfying resolution to this one is close to impossible and not worth the effort.